# Traceroute works but nc fails - Where is my port being blocked?

Tags: routing, tcp, traceroute, nc

I am trying to troubleshoot two Azure VNETs that have been peered together. Lets call these VNETs A and B. There are multiple services running on a VM in VNET A on different ports. I am trying to access them from a VM in VNET B.

I observe the following behaviour:

```
nc -vz vm-in-host-a.something.com 11294
Connection to vm-in-hosta.something.com 11294 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

nc -vz vm-in-host-a.something.com 11291
nc: connect to vm-in-host-a.something.com 11291 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
nc: connect to vm-in-host-a.something.com port 11291 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
nc: connect to vm-in-host-a.something.com 11291 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
```

Next I try the following:

```
usr/sbin/traceroute -I -4 -p 11294 vm-in-host-a.something.com
traceroute to vm-in-host-a.something.com (10.225.16.6), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  10.225.16.6 (10.225.16.6)  150.447 ms  150.485 ms  150.363 ms
```

And lastly, the following:

```
/usr/sbin/traceroute -I -4 -p 11291 vm-in-host-a.something.com
traceroute to vm-in-host-a.something.com (10.225.16.6), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  10.225.16.6 (10.225.16.6)  213.935 ms  213.760 ms  213.609 ms
```

Why would nc fail and traceroute succeed? Is there a way to check where exactly this port is being blocked? If its being blocked on VNET A or B or at exactly which point?

Answer (score 1):

You are using ICMP tracing (by specifying the `-I` switch), and, according to the [traceroute man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/traceroute), the `-p` option in this case

> specifies the initial icmp sequence value (incremented by each probe too).

So `traceroute` does not connect to the port you think it does, it simply sends out ICMP probes. To use a TCP port for scanning, you should use the `-T` switch instead of `-I`.